# Different URL's with the same website

Tags: iis, url

I have a website that currently uses a .com domain for all traffic. I am targeting the United Kingdom, United States, Canada, Australia and New Zealand.

Instead of this, I want something similar to what eBay does; ie if I'm in Australia I automatically get directed to eBay.com.au

Aside from registering the domains and pointing them all to the same website, is there anything else I need to do?

Also, what are the implications from an SEO perspective of having exactly the same website but with different URL's for each region?

Would having a .co.uk URL rank me better in the UK instead of having a .com?

Comment: If your websites are **exactly** the same, as you say, then having "local" domain names is a waste of time - most users won't care that they're from the UK but the website ends in ".com". I'd suggest if you want more than one website, you should localise the content.

Comment: The content would be different, so when you visit the UK site only people from the UK would appear. I'd add to the code something that detects the domain extension and display data valid to that country. However, static content would be the same.

Comment: Then they're not "exactly the same website". This isn't me being pedantic by the way; "how do I direct lots of different domain names to the same website" and "how do I generate lots of similar, but localised websites based on the same back-end content, and direct people to the right URL and localised data based on geolocation" are two very different problems, and you've essentially asked the first question while wanting the answer to the second.

Answer (score 1):

It is not just about having different DNS names. It would be useful to have different web servers in different countries and point your clients based on their location to the nearest web server.